# how to set cucumber environment variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, cucumber

I am having the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "newcucumber",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js",
    "firefox": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js -- --profile.desktop.env.browser ff"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.24.1",
    "cucumber": "^1.3.0",
    "firefox-profile": "^0.4.2",
    "geckodriver": "^1.1.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.12",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.0-beta-2"
  }
}
```

I run the program using:

```
npm test
```

I would like to set an environment variable for cucumber, such that I could run from the command line: `npm test firefox` or `npm test phantomjs`.

It could also be as a part of package.json 'scripts' as seen above, but I am not sure if I did it right. Invoking `npm run-script firefox`

How does one implement it, such that in the js code, like world.js or browser.js I grab the env variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once more, now I have got the answer I wanted to use in the first place:

This is how part of package.json (MIND!!! the syntax of quotation marks) looks like:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "cucumber-js",
    "firefox": "cucumber-js --world-parameters '{\"browser\":\"firefox\"}'",
    "chrome": "cucumber-js --world-parameters '{\"browser\":\"chrome\"}'",
    "safari": "cucumber-js --world-parameters '{\"browser\":\"safari\"}'",
    "phantomjs": "cucumber-js --world-parameters '{\"browser\":\"phantomjs\"}'"
  }
```

The JSON object is passed to World. In your World.js the code looks like this:

```
module.exports = function() {
  this.World = function(input) {
    console.log(input.browser); // Do whatever you want with the JSON (input) object
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that when you want to define env vars. By the way, it is not mandatory to add the whole path, npm will figure it out

```
{
  "name": "newcucumber",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cucumber-js",
    "firefox": "NODE_ENV=test cucumber-js -- --profile.desktop.env.browser ff"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.24.1",
    "cucumber": "^1.3.0",
    "firefox-profile": "^0.4.2",
    "geckodriver": "^1.1.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.12",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.0-beta-2"
  }
}
```

Comment: When I run with your proposal, the following is printed out:

         `> NODE_ENV=test cucumber-js -- --profile.desktop.env.browser ff

          fs.js:1574
               return binding.realpath(pathModule._makeLong(path), options.encoding);
                 

                 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, realpath '--profile.desktop.env.browser'
                at Error (native)
                at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1574:18)`

Answer (score 1):

I decided not to change something in node_modules or whatever, cause after the next `npm update <package>` the changes will be lost.

The Idea is to set the env variable:

1. Create a `start.sh` file in the directory where you call `npm test` from.
2. Write in `start.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   export BROWSER=$1
   npm test
   ```
3. Inside your `browser.js`or the file where you call your browsers type:

   ```
   var chrome = require('chromedriver'),
   phantom = require('phantomjs-prebuilt'),
   firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox'),
   webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
   ...

   console.log("What was passed into global env: ", process.env.BROWSER);
   switch(process.env.BROWSER) {
       case 'firefox':                             //Setup Firefox
           var capabilities = {
               'browserName' : 'firefox'
           }
           break; 
       case 'phantomjs':
           var capabilities = {
               'browserName' : 'phantomjs'
           }
           break;
       case 'chrome':
           var capabilities = {
               'browserName' : 'chrome'
           }
           break;
       }

   return browserHandle = new webdriver
       .Builder()
       .withCapabilities(capabilities)
       .build();
   ```

   4. Call `. start.sh firefox (phantomjs, chrome)`

Comment: All the proposed solutions from `@acontell` and `@Svabael` didn't work for my cucumber-js, it did all the time print out

      Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, realpath '--profile.desktop.env.browser' at Error (native) at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1574:18)

Comment: i love the idea of this solution - the start.sh file with the param. i prefer creating a json file and read the params from there rather than switch/case.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but, according to cucumber's CLI documentation, there's a way to pass data to the world constructor ([World parameters](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md), by the end of the page)

You could pass the browser to the World constructor and let it create the webdriver instance according to your choice.

I guess the script part in your package.json could be (more or less) as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "cucumber-js",
    "firefox": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --world-parameters <JSON>"
  }
```

where `<JSON>` would contain the info. about the browser type, etc. Hope it helps.

Comment: My problem with this is every single world class will do this when in essence you probably only need to set it once

Answer (score 0):

6axter82's solutions works for me...to some degree.
In order to pass in variables from command line, I have to add following adjustments.
(Environment: Windows 10 / VS Code / Command Prompt)

1. To execute from scripts property inside package.json, additional
   backslash () is needed.
   `"firefox": "cucumber-js --world-parameters '{\"browser\":\"firefox\"}'",`

   is converted into

   `"firefox": "cucumber-js --world-parameters {\\\"browser\\\":\\\"firefox\\\"}"`
2. (If default constructor is overridden by setWorldConstructor(World)) Create constructor for World as specified on [Cucumber.js/World Doc](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/world.md), specifically

   `function World({attach, parameters}) {
           this.attach = attach
           this.parameters = parameters
    }`
3. To reference parameter values inside World class (world.js), use following expression `this.parameters.browser`

Hope this helps.